# Convert Theano to Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, theano

I want to re-implement the Deep Kalman Models in Tensorflow.
The Theano version is available at: https://github.com/clinicalml/dmm

Are there any helpful websites that can give the instruction on how to convert Theano-Tensorflow?

Thank you in advance!